# Render Partial View from Javascript and pass model

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I need to create partial views dynamically which require a model that is initially used. I can serialize the model and pass it to a javascript function but I can't figure out how to pass using jquery api load.

Here's what I'm currently doing.

```
var loader = $('<div class="loader"></div>');
loader.load(url);
$(cl).append(loader);
```

I call the partial like this in the cshtml page. This works fine.

```
@Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/_PartialView.cshtml", Model);
```

Also, calling load like this works works as well.

```
load('@Url.Action("_PartialViewAction", "Home")')
```

The issue is, I need to pass the model with it from a javascript/jquery call.

**Update**

So this was my mistake. It must be a Friday morning thing - this is actually very simple to accomplish. I only need to pass the serialized data to the controller and it loads the partial view.

Comment: Could you give us more detail on your view code?

Comment: There is a lot that it depends on. What is `cl`, is your action you are targeting a POST or GET and can you confirm it indeed returns the HTML of the partial view? You have no handlers, how do you know the call is a success and hasn't returned in a failure? - I would use [**http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) , make the call to the action and assign a success/complete handler to inspect the return value. In success take the returned data and append it to your loader.

Comment: Going by your update,..yes, if you plan on passing data to the action you should include that so MVC can build the model for the partialview :) - Going by your original post I would have assumed the controller action was building the model itself.

Comment: You should have an action method which takes the type of your model as parameter (and http post type) which return the partial view result. Once you have that, use `$.ajax` to pass your JS object which you can generate using `@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))`

Comment: But if possible, you should send the minimal data from client (an Id or so) and rebuild the model in your server and use that.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the object into a javascript var:

```
<script>
  var viewModel = @Html.Raw(JsonNetConverter.Serialize(Model))
 </script>
```

or like this :

```
var viewModel = { VariationID: @Model.id, ProductID: @Model.product, InStock: @Model.isStock, Price: @Model.price };
```

And leter take it:

```
load('@Url.Action("_PartialViewAction", "Home")', viewModel)
```